# @auth/prisma-adapter how to configure auth.ts?

Tags: next.js, prisma, next.js13

I'm currently following a tutorial making a AirBnb clone with Next.js. In the register functionality chapter when adding the prisma adapter, the 2023 set up on https://authjs.dev/reference/adapter/prisma#setup
says to add [...nextauth].ts inside of pages/api/auth.
Now (2024) it says

> Add this adapter to your auth.ts Auth.js configuration object:...

I decided to just follow the tut and however I cant seem to able to log in registered users and get a status 404 error (api/auth/error) unless someone knows where to specifically look besides in network in dev tools